# Rails 4 ActiveAdmin CSV export yields "You are not authorized to perform this action." in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I am using "out of the box" installations of **Devise** gem and **ActiveAdmin** gem in my Rails 4 project. I have an ActiveAdmin model that works fine as an index page on the ActiveAdmin page. I set up CSV like the documents show, but when I load up the .csv link, I get this error: "**You are not authorized to perform this action.**" in the browser window. Nothing shows up in the rails log.

Here is the ActiveAdmin model code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :text
    actions
  end


  csv do
    column :id
    column :text
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/4867  What do you have for download_links?